# how to display hidden rows in ms excel?

Tags: spreadsheet, excel-2003

I believe I don't have to put my code here since this is not code related stuff, anyway I have a MS Excel 2003 Spreadsheet and it was being passed to me by one of my office mates, I don't know what they did to it, but a certain column(specifically the A column) is missing. I tried to view it on print preview, and somehow it shows the hidden column I've been looking. Now what bothers me is that how is it possible to be on the print preview, and when I go back to the normal view the column A is nowhere in sight. I tried to highlight everything and tried to Unhide/Hide it but it is still not there. I hope someone could guide me through this stuff. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the two columns between, right click on header, click unhide.
For example: [image]

Comment: tried this earlier but it isn't what i wanted. anyway thanks for the response..:)

Comment: but your response is also acceptable, tried it many times before..:)

Comment: :D, i forgot about unfreeze pane. i'm making office software for about 10 years, and excel did not improve it any more.

Comment: wow, that is a LOOOONNNNGG span of doing that office software stuff..anyway, thanks for the response, Sensei..:-)

Comment: :D u are welcome. Here's our latest work, WPS Office on Android https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cn.wps.moffice&feature=more_from_developer

Comment: sorry, here is English edition: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cn.wps.moffice_eng

Answer (score 1):

Eureka... Since no one responded and luckily I got a tip from one of my TRUSTED guru, then he told me to go to Window, and select Unfreeze Panes, and VOILA, the missing column that I have been looking for has been found. Awwwww Yeahhhh....

Comment: i believe you found the answer quickly..:)

Answer (score 0):

Another possible issue which I encountered recently is that you may have a filter turned on in the file - so check to ensure they are turned off!